# How to make a "Winter queen" cocktail?

Tags: chocolate, restaurant-mimicry, cocktails

A few days ago, I had a cocktail called "Winter queen". It may have been a specialty of the place where I had it, I couldn't find any recipe for it when I searched for it. The menu listed it as "a hot chocolate beverage with rum, topped with cream".

Based on the taste, I can say that the thing had rather low alcohol content, but the rum aroma was fairly strong. Also, I am not sure what liquid they used for the chocolate "beverage" - there must have been some milk in it, but I don't think it was straight full-fat milk. I suspect that it also had other spices, maybe some vanilla, and it was slightly sweet, but not oversweetened. The cream was only a swirl of whipped cream from a NO-bottle, with some chocolate-deco sprinkles on top.

I tried to copy it at home, but couldn't get the same result. I started with semi-sweet chocolate, melted with sweetened milk, added vanilla aroma, a pinch of salt, and Bacardi Gold rum. With a small amount of rum, it didn't have enough taste. When I added more rum, it got very bitter and alcoholic. Also, something with the fat content wasn't right - the original drink was less rich, but still quite smooth, unlike water-based hot chocolate.

Should I have tried to do it some other way? Did I use the wrong rum? Would it have helped to cook the rum first, so some of the alcohol evaporates? Is there a better way to mix it? And what about the smooth-without-fat problem?

Comment: Where did you have this cocktail?

Comment: There is rum extract, that may help getting the rum flavor w/o the alcohol.

Comment: @KatieK in a place in Stuttgart - strangely, it had a Maredo brand on the outside, but it didn't have the Maredo menu inside - it was more of a bistrot-like place, with mostly drinks and cakes and a few snacks/salads/antipasti, not a steakhouse. I checked the Maredo website, they don't mention such cocktails.

Comment: @rumtscho - I was thinking of calling them, but perhaps not.

Comment: I agree with derobert - rum flavour without alcohol suggests a rum syrup.

Comment: As to the rum, there are lots and lots of rums out there, and they all taste different. Using a darker rum might help in this case, since lighter rums tend to have less flavor. Maybe even a spiced rum (the one I have on hand, Kraken, has a distinct vanilla flavor).

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of "Winter Queen" cocktail

But if you're talking about the "SNOW QUEEN COCKTAIL", I found the recipe here:

> ## [Snow Queen Cocktail Recipe](http://www.cocktailmaking.co.uk/displaycocktail.php/9564-Snow-Queen)
>
> ### Snow Queen Cocktail Ingredients
>
> - 1 part [vanilla vodka](http://www.cocktailmaking.co.uk/displayingredient.php/2236-vanilla-vodka)
> - 1 part [Bailey's Irish Cream](http://www.cocktailmaking.co.uk/displayingredient.php/3540-Baileys-Irish-Cream)
> - 1 part [creme de menthe](http://www.cocktailmaking.co.uk/displayingredient.php/46-creme-de-menthe)
> - 3 parts [Fresh Single Cream](http://www.cocktailmaking.co.uk/displayingredient.php/10084-Fresh-Single-Cream)
> - 3 parts [milk](http://www.cocktailmaking.co.uk/displayingredient.php/92-milk)
> - 1 dash [chocolate syrup](http://www.cocktailmaking.co.uk/displayingredient.php/136-chocolate-syrup)
>
> ### Instructions
>
> Mix the Vanilla Vodka, Baileys and Creme de Menthe with ice in a shaker then drain into a glass omitting the ice (or you can cheat/skip this part by chilling the Vodka and Baileys in a fridge). Then add the Cream and a dash of Chocolate Syrup, stir, add the Milk and stir again.
>
> This is based on the recipe for the popular but seasonal Snow Queen served in Revolution Vodka bars. Now you don't have to wait until Winter to get one! Note: All the ingredients should be correct but the Milk and Fresh Cream measurements are a best guess. Experiment and enjoy :)

Comment: Interesting. I am sure mine didn't have creme de menthe or Bailey's, but it could have been a simplification of the original.

Comment: Maybe this recipe might help you find the one you are looking for?